# Tomcat 9. How to pass catalina.out to service logs (journalctl)

Tags: tomcat, logging, centos, journal, catalina.out

I'm using Tomcat 9 in a Centos machine. The logs from Tomcat applications are generated at /opt/tomcat/logs.catalina.out. Is there a way to pass these logs to service logs (journalctl -u MyTomcat.service -f)?

I trigger my service from /etc/systemd/system.MyTomcat.service

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/startup.sh (startup.sh call catalina.sh start)

I'm able to see the logs in catalina.out but journcalctl has only these rows but catalina includes all the logging from my apps

```
 Feb 28 08:14:39 192.168.1.2 systemd[1]: Starting My Tomcat Service... 
 Feb 28 08:14:39 192.168.1.2systemd[1]:  Started My Tomcat Service. 
 Feb 28 08:14:39 192.168.1.2tomcat[23222]: Tomcat started.
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi i found a solution for the post. Here is what I did if there is someone else that is looking for it.

```
1. /etc/rsyslog.conf
   #add imfile module
   $ModLoad imfile
   $IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
   ...
   *.* @@<SYSLOG_SERVER ADDRESS>:<SYSLOG SERVER PORT>

2. /etc/rsyslog.d/catalina_ruleset.conf
   template(
     name = "my_template"
     type = "string"
     string = "<%PRI%>%timegenerated% %HOSTNAME% %syslogtag%: %msg%"
   )
   input(
     type="imfile"
     File="<catalina.out location>"
     Tag="MyTag"
     PersistStateInterval="1"
     reopenOnTruncate="on"
     freshStartTail="on"
     ruleset="My_ruleset"
   )
  ruleset(name="My_ruleset") {
     action(
         type="omfwd"
         template=""my_template""
         queue.saveonshutdown="on"
         action.resumeRetryCount="-1"
         Target="<SYSLOG_SERVER ADDRESS>"
         Port="<SYSLOG SERVER PORT>"
         Protocol="tcp"
       )
     }
```